# Show derivative positive then strictly increasing on $R$

Tags: calculus

I know a differentiable function is strictly increasing on [a,b] if the derivative is positive on [a,b]. But what if the function is differentiable on the real line and the derivative is positive, can we then conclude that it is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$? The mean value theorem is only stated for intervals, does it work on $(-\infty,\infty)$, or is there a counterexample to the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does work on $(-\infty, \infty)$.

This is because if you take any $x,y\in\mathbb R$ such that $x<y$, you then know that $f$ is strictly increasing on $[x, y]$, and that tells you that $f(x)<f(y)$.

Since $x,y$ are arbitrary, you know that $f$ is increasing on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

For every pair of real numbers $x,y$ with $x < y$ we can use the Mean-Value theorem.

From the Mean-value theorem, there exist at least a point t between x and y such that,

$[f(y)-f(y)]/[y-x] = f'(t) > 0$ , as we are given derivative is positive.

That implies $f(y)-f(x) > 0$ i.e  $f(y) > f(x)$ (this is the property of strictly increasing functions). Therefore we can claim it for every pair of real numbers.
This implies that f is strictly increasing in a real field.